# Kundera / HBase / Spring: Timeout trying to initialize / update the schema

Tags: spring, hibernate, hbase, kundera

I am using Spring boot to create a web service and want to persist my data model in HBase. I want to use Kundera for this task. However, I cannot get it to work. When spinning up the application, it starts up, freezes for about a minute and runs into a timeout. Here are some snippets of my configuration:

My persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="hbase_pu">
        <provider>com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence</provider>     
        <properties>            
            <property name="kundera.nodes" value="my-hbase-server.example.com"/>
            <property name="kundera.port" value="2181"/>
            <property name="kundera.keyspace" value="mykeyspace"/>
            <property name="kundera.dialect" value="hbase"/>
            <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class" value="com.impetus.client.hbase.HBaseClientFactory" />
            <property name="kundera.ddl.auto.prepare" value="update"/>             
        </properties>       
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My configuration for the entity manager:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    return bean;
}
```

When trying to run this, it seems to spin up okay:

```
... many info outputs ...
2014-12-10 09:07:05.682  INFO 5194 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper           : Initiating client connection, connectString=my-hbase-server.example.com:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x556effa0, quorum=my-hbase-server.example.com:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
2014-12-10 09:07:05.694  INFO 5194 --- [ne002.int:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Opening socket connection to server my-hbase-server.example.com/x.x.x.x:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2014-12-10 09:07:05.698  INFO 5194 --- [ne002.int:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Socket connection established to my-hbase-server.example.com/x.x.x.x:2181, initiating session
2014-12-10 09:07:05.780  INFO 5194 --- [ne002.int:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Session establishment complete on server my-hbase-server.example.com/x.x.x.x:2181, sessionid = 0x14a2e04a4ca001f, negotiated timeout = 40000
2014-12-10 09:07:05.820  INFO 5194 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.h.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry     : ClusterId read in ZooKeeper is null
```

Then, it freezes for about a minute, after that, it crashes:

```
2014-12-10 09:08:05.703 ERROR 5194 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.i.c.h.s.HBaseSchemaManager             : Either check for network connection or table isn't in enabled state, Caused by:
... large stack trace, interesting section: ...
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the locations
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.isTableAvailable(ConnectionManager.java:919)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.isTableAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:1127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.isTableAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:1135)
    at com.impetus.client.hbase.schemamanager.HBaseSchemaManager.update(HBaseSchemaManager.java:100)
    ... 165 more
```

What is going wrong here? Did I miss anything, and if yes, what?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it has to do with Zookeeper. The entry point for hbase is hard-coded to `/hbase`, and the entry point of my server was different. But alas, Kundera seems to be incomplete, `KunderaCriteriaQuery` has many `// TODO Auto-generated method stub` and `return null` so unfortunately it is unusable for my task.

Comment: JPA criteria query is still under development. Most of features available with named query or JPQL are supported, but other than that JPA Criteria interface offers a lot! and supporting each and everything with NoSQL databases is not possible and probably not required. If you looking for anything specific, could you please drop an email at kundera@impetus.co.in ?